# Is there a way to call model while creating controller in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to make 'use App\Models\Model-name' in any controller i create..is there a way to do this ?!
I searched for this and found something like use auto-load file but didn't get the idea.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Extending a controller that has this won't do it?

Comment: Hello, You want to have a global acces to a model across all the controllers instead of calling it one by one or you want the controller to have the model defined at the controller when you create it?

Comment: @kerbh0lz I want to when i creating new controller,,In this controller i want to use the model that related to this controller like this 'use App\Models\ModelName'.

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro yes the second one i want.

Comment: We're not discussing IDEs, OP was trying to get the single line command. He can declare them manually if he needs more models.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible! As per the Laravel documentation, you can use the following command:

`php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource --model=Photo`

Comment: That's about creating the model at the same time as the controller, not using a model in all controllers.

Comment: @onlineThomas Yes but it will "use App\Photo" (or whatever the model is) when you create the controller. If the model already exists, it will not create another model.

Comment: @onlineThomas Exactly that what i looking for.

Comment: @SawyerClever Thanks for help but not this what i looking for.

Comment: @AhmedHassan If that is _not_ what you're looking for you need to edit your question and be more specific in what you actually want. "_yes the second one i want_" That's what this answer solves.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a controller with the model try:

```
php artisan make:controller YourModelController --model=Models/YourModel
```